# Draw back of a hybrid php and js file

Tags: javascript, php

I remember back when I first got into the industry, my then employer's IT manager had made the choice of having a .js.php file extension on the files. This allowed him to, I believe, fool the CMS (joomla) into allowing him to inject the two languages at once.  My question is this, as I've never done this to date, is there actual benefits of doing this, or does it open up your system for more problems then it's worth?

Comment: A Php file can display html as well as include `<script>` tags for javascript.  I'm not sure how else the two languages would combine.

Comment: @NathanielWendt I think the asker wants to have a .js file served by PHP. I'm having trouble thinking of any problems this could solve and many that it could introduce.

Comment: Well it would allow you to build a custom JS file using PHP logic and immediately converting those PHP variables into javascript ones. There can be benefits to that if your code is organized certain ways...but I agree about it introducing WAY more problems.

Comment: Two extensions are not necessary.  You could have as easily used a `.php` extension by itself.  There are performance drawbacks to mixing PHP and javascript code in your static assets.  You should try not to do it unless necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is a good way to do it the way your manager wants to. Most times, the Manager or Stakeholder, knows about the Product Domain, but not know about the implementation (It is not his Job). What i want to say: If you don't feel good about the current state, communicate it.

If you do it via PHP, i can bet, your code wouldn't be conform with the input, processing, output principe.

Normaly you would compile JS with something like Closure Compiler (For optimization) and let the webserver handle the delivery to the client. No needs to start the PHP Interpreter  and think about header and caching (Performance).

For interaction beetween Data and Javascript you have 2 Ways. The best would be to solve the problem anonymously via CSS Selktors like the JQuery way. Alternative you can make use of functions with parameters direct in your View. The JS Library should be referenced as Script.

```
//Maybe you want to decode a JSON Object, and encode it as Json in PHP Side
var person = {
    firstName:"John",
    lastName :"Doe",
    id       :5566
};
providePerson(person);
```