# How to create this type of array in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

We can create this type of array in javascript -

```
var locations = [
    ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
    ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
    ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
    ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
    ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
];
```

But, how can we create this type of array in PHP ?
And what is this type of array known as ?

Thanks,

Comment: `array(array('Bondi Beach', '-33....'), ..............);`?

Comment: o_o this is a really know multidimensional array... two level, so you can see it as a matrix , etc, etc, does really array got name?

Comment: 'What is this type of array known as?' A bad array... Don't mix types in an array, even if JS lets you. Ask yourself why you would be doing this.

Comment: @Blunderfest What do you mean about "don't mix types" ?

Comment: I really recommend to read the documentation, which covers everything you asked about: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: @lolka_bolka the above array contains both strings and numbers in the same array, which is a bad practice in JS (not familiar with PHP).

Comment: @Blunderfest I think, that is no problem in js too. Why not? Of course, objects are more usefull, but I don't think, that is a bad practice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this if you are using `PHP >= 5.4` (credits to [putvande](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2539720/putvande) for pointing out the specific version)

```
$locations = [
    ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
    ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
    ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
    ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
    ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
];
```

If you use older versions of PHP:

```
$locations = array(
    array('Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4),
    array('Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5),
    array('Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3),
    array('Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2),
    array('Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1)
);
```

**Your additional Question from Comments**

As commented, in future ask a new Question, because the format of this side is, one Question, different Soltution to it.

> Works.... I want to pass this array to javascript function parameter,
>   how can i be able to achieve that?

I have answered a simmilar Question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24088245/2441442), basicly you `echo` the Javascript the same way, you would with HTML

```
echo "var locations = [
    ['$sampleVar1', $sampleVar2, $sampleVar3, $sampleVar4],
    ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
    ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
    ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
    ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
];";
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad. But it is only since PHP 5.4

Comment: Works....
I want to pass this array to javascript function parameter, how can i be able to achieve that ?

Comment: @AshishGogna, i have answered a different Question here with the same aproach: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24088245/2441442 If you have further Question to this, feel free to ask a new Question. This is the Way the Community works here. It is not a Forum. Welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: Basicly you simple `echo` the JavaScript, as you echo the HTML

Answer (score 0):

Just normally put data as inner arrays(multi dimensional array).

```
$arr = array(array('Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4),
array('Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2),
array('Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work ..

```
$locations=array(
    0=>array('Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4),
    1=>array('Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5),
    2=>array('Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3),
    3=>array('Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2),
    4=>array('Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1)
);
```